# Get the error when creating the view “cleartool mkview -tag $view-name $view-name" with Clearcase UCM Plugin 1.7.4

Tags: plugins, view, jenkins, clearcase

Get the error when creating the view “`cleartool mkview -tag $view-name $view-name`" with plugin 1.7.4.

Additional `view-name` added at the end of command line.

In the additional arguments I placed the UNC path to the view. In case I don't add it it gives me 
"... UNC path should be provided..." error.
Log:

```
Building remotely on builder
[test] $ cleartool mkview -tag jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int_22 \\builder\cc_views\jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int_22 jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int_22
cleartool: Error: Extra arguments: "jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int_22"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cleartool mkview -tag $view-name $view-name
```

is incorrect.

You need either `-vws` (for the view storage path: your UNC path) or `-stg` (for the name of a view storage)

See [`cleartool mkview` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm).

So it should be:

```
cleartool mkview -tag $view-name
```

with additional argument: `-stg a_view-storage-unc_path`

---

The [OP ZeevT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126593/zeevt) adds in the comments:

> Tried now using snapshot view, but same failure. 
>   See below the cmd generated by Jenkins:

```
Building remotely on build-xp [Hello World] 
$ cleartool mkview -snapshot -tag jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int \\build-xp\CC_views\jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int.vws jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int 

cleartool: Error: Extra arguments: "jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int" – ZeevT 2 days ago
```

I mention that the view storage path for a snapshot view should be preceded by `-vws`, and the OP confirms:

> **For snapshot view `-vws` solved the problem** –

So there is still an issue for dynamic views...

Comment: I suppose I will monitor http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/JIRA-JENKINS-12272-Get-the-error-when-creating-the-view-quot-cleartool-mkview-tag-view-name-view-name-td4253931.html as well ;)

Comment: The problem is that the actual command generated by Jenkins CC plugins: ClearCase UCM Baseline 1.7.4, ClearCase Plugin 1.3.7. So the additional view name added at the end.

Comment: @ZeevT It looks like a regression of a bug fixed in CC UCM Baseline 1.7.2 plugin: http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-8168

Comment: @ZeevT: and for *snapshot* view, you should see a `-snap` parameter: `cleartool mkview -snap -tag ...`. You do try to build a snapshot view, right?

Comment: Tried now using snapshot view, but same failure. See below the cmd generated by Jenkins: Building remotely on build-xp
[Hello World] $ cleartool mkview -snapshot -tag jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int \\build-xp\CC_views\jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int.vws jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int
cleartool: Error: Extra arguments: "jenkins_Official_G4_FW_Platform_Dev_int"

Comment: @ZeevT: for dynamic view, I confirm it shouldn't repeat the name of the view at then end. For snapshot view, the name of the view can play the role of root directory, howvever you need '`-vws`' before your UNC path.

Comment: @ZeevT: excellent! Dynamic views should work with the UNC path (without `-vws`) of their view storage. Or you need to specify more: `{ –stg/loc { view-stgloc-name | –aut/o } | [ –hos/t hostname –hpa/th host-storage-pname –gpa/th global-storage-pname ]`. Ie either a storage name, or the