# Simple deployment from ClearCase on Unix

Tags: clearcase

I have recently joined a team that has several applications that perform workload automation.  They use ClearCase for version control but the development and test environments are (I surmise due to a lack of ClearCase expertise within the team) not checked out/deployed out of ClearCase but simply FTP-ed to respective Unix servers from Window.  I said "simple deployment" because all the code is interpreted (Perl and shell) so no need to compile.  Needless to say, many things are wrong with this approach, most specifically the lack of version management in these environments from the point of deployment onward.

So I would like to bind our deployments to the repository and start controlling changes but I am only a ClearCase novice.  My specific question is: what is it that I deploy, a VIEW or a STREAM? I would say the latter cause views are user-specific while (according to my understanding) a stream is a project trunk off of each view is like a branch and views are integrated into their stream.

If anyone has any pointers on some useful yet succint and lightweight ClearCase tutorials for an "accidental" CM liason, please share.

Alternatively, if you think this task is suitable for **Jenkins**, despite being relatively simple (no build/compile involved) please chime in.

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the [Jenkins ClearCase UCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin) (in combination with [Jenkins ClearCase plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin)) in order to start jobs based on a ClearCase Stream

[image: config]

Jenkins will create an UCM snapshot view based on the stream you will specify in it.

See also, for more on the stream:

- "[Difference between branches and streams in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880031/integration-stream-vs-integration-view-in-clearcase)"
- "[Integration stream vs integration view in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880031/integration-stream-vs-integration-view-in-clearcase)"

Comment: i surmise i can do this Jenkins deployments on Unix CL and not use the GUI you submitted, correct?

Comment: @foampile I suppose so, but haven't tested it.

Comment: one more question, Von -- i have several views created and wanted to deploy one (i guess 'update' in CC terminology).  i went to my Unix home dir and did 'cleartool update' but got '<MY_HOME_DIR> is not a valid snapshot view path'

Comment: @foampile That seems normal: for a snapshot view, you need to go to the root directory of said snapshot view.

Comment: so in order to be able to deploy a view to ANY WORKING DIR, i should make it dynamic, true or false?

Comment: @foampile false: dynamic view is a network access mounted on /view. All dynamic views are mounted there, followed by their names : /view/aDynViewTag.

Comment: so how can i check out my view to any working directory (e.g. /home/MY_ID/project/xyz/) ?

Comment: @foampile when you create a snapshot view, you indicate a root directory for that view : you can only update it there. To have it elsewhere, you need to create another snapshot view.

Comment: by "root directory" do you mean the local working directory in which the code base is checked out?

Comment: @foampile correct, you can see the difference between dynamic and snapshot views here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378 and more examples on snapshot views here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207409/proper-cleartool-mkview-for-clearcase-snapshot-view-creation

Comment: @foampile Jenkins will create its own views (like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8704153/6309). Snapshot views only, as explained in http://www.praqma.com/stories/ccucm