# Clearcase with Maven Release plugin in Jenkins how should it work?

Tags: maven, jenkins, clearcase, nexus, maven-release-plugin

I'm not sure how maven release plugin works with clearcase. To clearify How should this maven work in clearcase.

Jenkins is building on branch test_5.0.0, in jenkins there is a job called test_5.0.0 
This job is pointing to branch test_5.0.0 The pom file version is 5.0.0-SNAPSHOT

how does the release plugin in maven work with clearcase, will it baseline? (I have read it create labels?)

When the new pom version is 5.0.1-SNAPSHOT after releasing. The job name is wrong, also the branch name is wrong in this scenaro. So for each release one has to create a new branch and new job.

I have this setup in a git world and now trying to setup clearcase with jenkins, maven and nexus. All is building and working but I can not find a good release flow with the current branching strategy the CM has setup in clearcase. What do you suggest? how do you work with maven release and clearcase?

Edit:
When working with clearcase with UCM we where using ANT and IVY. We did not use any "snapshots" basically everything was release builds in maven terms. This took away the need for a so called release and we baselined every build and promoted the latest build as Release.

I also found [this link](http://www.gungus.se/blog/?p=212), but does this apply to UCM and it seems it labels instead of baseline?

/Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read in the "[Apache Maven SCM implementation page](http://maven.apache.org/scm/clearcase.html)", the maven release would only work with UCM snapshot views only, not base ClearCase.

So the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) would create an UCM baseline, not a simple label.
That creation takes place, for instance, with [`mvn release:branch`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html).

ClearCase is very different from git (see "[What are the basic ClearCase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309)")

Since you would use UCM only, you need to take into account the branching/**[stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5636931/6309)** hierarchy promoted by that methodology (UCM: Unified Change Management)

See "[Integration stream vs integration view in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880266/6309)" and "[Simple deployment from ClearCase on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938346/6309)".

Comment: I have worked with clearcase before both base and UCM. When working with clearcase with UCM we where using ANT and IVY. We did not use any "snapshots" bacisally everything was release builds in maven terms. The concept of having snapshot and releases comes into play when using maven. I'm being torn trying to follow maven practices with having snapshot and releases seperate, which seems to requires a different branch strategy to avoid making new jenkins jobs. I have clarified my questions above.

Comment: @user1043825 just to be sure, snapshot, in my answer, refers to ClearCase snapshot views, and has nothing to do with snapshot vs. release in maven.